# Using temporary files and folders in Web2py app

Tags: python, web2py

I am relatively new to web development and very new to using Web2py. The application I am currently working on is intended to take in a CSV upload from a user, then generate a PDF file based on the contents of the CSV, then allow the user to download that PDF. As part of this process I need to generate and access several intermediate files that are specific to each individual user (these files would be images, other pdfs, and some text files). I don't need to store these files in a database since they can be deleted after the session ends, but I am not sure the best way or place to store these files and keep them separate based on each session. I thought that maybe the subfolders in the `sessions` folder would make sense, but I do not know how to dynamically get the path to the correct folder for the current session. Any suggestions pointing me in the right direction are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error "TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found" and I had to store just a  link in the session to the uploaded document in the db or maybe the upload folder in your case. I would store it to upload to proceed normally, and then clear out the values and the file if not 'approved'?

Answer (score 0):

If the information is not confidential in similar circumstances, I directly write the temporary files under /tmp.